# What's the least privileges of NetLocalGroupAddMembers?

Tags: winapi, privilege

Anyone who know "What's the least privileges of NetLocalGroupAddMembers?"
Appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netlocalgroupaddmembers):

> If you call this function on a domain controller that is running
>   Active Directory, access is allowed or denied based on the access
>   control list (ACL) for the securable object. The default ACL permits
>   only **Domain Admins and Account Operators** to call this function. On a
>   member server or workstation, only **Administrators and Power Users** can
>   call this function.

This is confirmed by [Requirements for Network Management Functions on Active Directory Domain Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/NetMgmt/requirements-for-network-management-functions-on-active-directory-domain-controllers):

> For updates, the default ACL permits only Domain Administrators and
>   Account Operators to write information. One exception is that users
>   can change their own password and set the usri*_usr_comment field.
>   **Another exception is that Account Operators cannot modify
>   administration accounts**.

and [Requirements for Network Management Functions on Servers and Workstations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/NetMgmt/requirements-for-network-management-functions-on-servers-and-workstations):

> By default, only Administrators and Power Users can write information.

Comment: Thank you very much, Anders. it is the answer.

Comment: @glover Then you should mark it as the answer by clicking on the `V`.